# How to model a (Java) Enum in a Database (with SQL92)

Tags: java, sql, database, enums, modeling

Hi am modelling an Entity with a column named "Gender". In the application code, the gender is supposed to be an (Java) Enum type, with 2 values (MALE and FEMALE).. how would you model it, knowing that Enums as Datatype are not part of the generic SQL (language) 92.

It the data model would have to be portable, in order to be used by several DBMS (Mysql, Oracle, Derby) and several persistence provider (JPA, Hibernate, JDBC).
I feel, it hits at 2  levels:
- first the level of the Schema and the entity (store the enums as -VAR-CHAR or INT)
- second the level of the app code (JDBC doesn't support enums, JPA does but it depends on the implementation)

Is there a generic solution, applicable for example to an Mysql DBMS ?
Thanks !!

Comment: Modell? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGMnhz6ibTY :)

Comment: sorry i am from germany ;) my English will definitely improve ;)

Comment: Not a problem! I just like to post funny things in comments to lighten the atmosphere. :D

Comment: @arthur Although I'm from Germany, too, I'd say it's `model` not `modell` or `modal` :) - @Almo :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically adopt the following solution, which gives a fully normalised database schema.

1. Create a dedicated table to represent your enumeration; e.g. `Colour`.  The table will have two columns:

   - An **ID** column (primary key).  Typically an auto-incrementing `int`, smallint or `tinyint`.
   - A **name** column (candidate key).  This will be a `varchar` whose value should be identical to the Java enumeration.
2. Create a Java enum: Colour with identical values to the `Colour` table in the database.
3. Assuming you now have a "Data" table containing records that reference the `Colour` table, implement a stored procedure for inserting a record, which takes the Colour String value (as described by your Java enum); e.g.

   CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertRecord
     @colour varchar(32)
   AS
   ...

The stored procedure will perform the necessary String-to-int translation allowing your data table to reference a the Colour table via an int foreign key.

Similarly you can create a view onto your data table(s) that will join to the Colour table behind the scenes to present a denormalised via of your data back to the application or end user.

The alternative to the stored procedure approach is that you read and cache the ordinal, name mappings within your application on startup.  This has the advantage of being able to verify the integrity of your Java Colour enum compared with the contents of your Colour table in the database.

Comment: it seems to be the more "secure" and "portable" approach. I could port the schema and the data to all other DBMS.. just need to change the syntax of the stored procedure. I'll take that, thanks !!

Comment: You're welcome.  One thing that's nice about it is it doesn't fail (in a nasty way) if someone changes the order of the enum values in the Java enum definition.  Conversely if you rely on ordinal to determine the int key to write to the database and someone changes the enum value order you introduce a horrific bug where you misinterpret any previously stored data!

Answer (score 1):

Enums have at least two properties by which they can be identified: an ordinal (the position of the instance in the enum list) and a name. Both could be stored in the database and be used to retrieve the correct enum instance.

If you're using an OR-mapper like Hibernate it'll do that for you, otherwise you need to manually convert the enum to an integer/long or a string and vice versa.

To make it safer you could add a custom property to your enum and provide a getter gor the property as well as aconversion function for property->enum value. That way you're free to reorder and rename the enum values as long as you don't change that id property.

Comment: Yepp, this approach is the fastest.. give it all the hibernate.. but what if i want to port the Schema to a application code which uses JDBC and doesn't support the notion of Enums ?

Comment: @arthur as I said "_If_ you're using an OR-mapper ..." - you don't have to do that. We're doing what I described in my third paragraph and that works fine and without having to rely on Hibernate. This would also work with JDBC etc.