# PostgreSQL string to int translation in stored procedure

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to implement the accepted answer of this question:

[How to model a (Java) Enum in a Database (with SQL92)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978089/how-to-model-a-java-enum-in-a-database-with-sql92)

And here's my current implementation:

Gender enum:

```
public enum Gender {

    MALE,
    FEMALE

}
```

Gender table:

```
create table gender (
    gender_id bigserial not null,
    name text not null,
    primary key(gender_id)
);
```

User table:

```
create table system_user (
    user_id bigserial not null,
    username text not null,
    gender_id bigint references gender(gender_id),
    primary key(user_id)
);

create trigger update_gender_enum_table before insert or update on system_user
    for each row execute procedure update_gender_enum_table();
```

Trigger:

```
create or replace function update_gender_enum_table() returns trigger as $update_gender_enum_table$
    begin
        if not exists(select name from gender g where g.name = new.gender_id::text limit 1)
        then
             insert into gender (name) values (new.gender_id);
        end if;

        new.gender_id = (select gender_id from gender g where g.name = new.gender_id::text limit 1);

        return new;

    end;
$update_gender_enum_table$ language plpgsql;
```

At the moment insert statement is failing because second parameter is text and not integer:

```
insert into system_user (username, gender_id) values ('my_username', 'MALE');

ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "MALE"
```

Is there any way to pass string as value to integer field? Or am I approaching this in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id field for your enum.

```
public enum Gender {

    private int id;

    MALE(1),
    FEMALE(2);

    Gender(int id) {
        this.id=id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public static Gender valueById(int id) {
        for(Gender gender : values()) {
            if(id == gender.id) {
                return gender;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported id: "+id+" for enum "+Gender.class.getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

I've written the code directly into this editor so it might contain som syntax errors.

You can also use the ordinal of the enum, but beware that this value might change if you add more genders (I.e. unknown) and therefore might not be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you trying to compare integer with text?

```
select name from gender g where g.name = new.gender_id::text limit 1
```

So you are trying to compare e.g. MALE with 3?

How your application shows genders to the users? Doesn't it come from gender table?

If you want to add new gender (so new row in gender table) you need to know name value, and insert it into gender, id column is not important, you will only insert the value into referencing system_user table.